# Updating Yaml using Groovy

Tags: java, groovy, yaml

I have the following Yaml file that I am trying to update, depending on whether a value for a particular key exits.

If `productName` with a value of `test` exists in the Yaml file, I want to update its respective URL `productUrl` with a new value.

If I have a new `productName` called `test` that does not exist in the Yaml file, I want to be able to add a new entry to the Yaml file for this `productName` and its `productUrl`.

```
  products:
    - productName: abc
      productUrl: https://company/product-abc
    - productName: def
      productUrl: https://company/product-def
    - productName: ghi
      productUrl: https://company/product-ghi
    - productName: jkl
      productUrl: https://company/product-jkl
    - productName: mno
      productUrl: https://company/product-mno
    - productName: pqr
      productUrl: https://company/product-pqr
```

This is what I have so far but I'm not sure if this can be re-written in a much cleaner way, or if there's a bug in my approach.

```
@Grab('org.yaml:snakeyaml:1.17')
import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml

Yaml parser = new Yaml()
def p = parser.load(("company.yml" as File).text)
Boolean isProductNew = true

p.company.products.each { i ->
  if (i.productName == 'test') {
    i.productUrl = 'https://company/product-new-test'
    isProductNew = false
  }
}

if (isProductNew) {
  p.company.products << ["productName": "test", "productUrl": "https://company/product-test"]
}
println p
```

Comment: "Is there a bug" can be answered by checking if it works. If `productName` is unique then it can be retrieved with `find`. If it isn't found you add the item, if it is you update it, then write it back out.

Comment: you want to save the changed data back to the file?

Answer (score 0):

You can put the code in a cleaner way:

```
def prod = p.company.products.find{ it.productName == 'test' }
if( !prod ){
  prod = [productName: "test"] 
  p.company.products << prod
}
product.productUrl = "https://company/product-test"
```

Comment: But if a productName with test is found, then I want to update the productUrl. If productName with test is NOT found, then the above statement works. So it's just missing the other condition

Comment: I see. Updated the answer